# Visual Studio Shell 2014 - hide exception settings tool window

Tags: c#, vspackage, visual-studio-shell

I have an existing shell app and after the shell upgrade (from 12 to 14) the Exception settings tool window is included in the app.

I would like to hide it due to it makes no sense in my app.

Do you have any idea how to deregister it? I think closing automatically is not enough because the Windows/Reset Window layout open it again.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meanwhile I have found the solution. It is working when you add the followings to the pkgundef file:

```
[$RootKey$\Packages\{d549bc66-c17b-4409-8729-583e60dc0bc1}]
[$RootKey$\ToolWindows\{605322a2-17ae-43f4-b60f-766556e46c87}]
```

it removes the VSDebugCoreUI package and the tool window

Answer (score 0):

What worked in previous version was to activate the line

```
<Define name="No_ExceptionsWindow"/>
```

in the `ApplicationCommands.vsct` included in the solution created by Visual Studio. This disabled the menu item "Debug -> Exceptions".

The line (in a disabled commented-out was) is still created in the newer Visual Studio versions but doesn't work any more. This is clearly a bug caused by Microsoft when they implemented the new cool Exception Settings tool window. Either they completely forgot to include the checking for the "No_ExceptionsWindow" define or they renamed the define without adapting the Visual Studio Solution Template for VS Shell projects.

I would contact the Visual Studio Team at Microsoft directly. They might fix this bug in future updates or they might be able to tell you what string to define to disable the Exception Settings Tool Window.